# Unable to remove Dynamics 365 Appointment's Optional and Required flelds value using Web API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm trying to remove Required and Optional Parties from an Appointment using Dynamics 365 Web API. I have tried "activityparties" entity to delete the values but no luck.

**Request:**

```
DELETE https://xxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/appointments(EE4C7268-81B7-E811-8143-3863BB368D98)/activitypointer_activity_parties_required(79ea68eb-4304-e911-8147-3863bb2eb450)
```

**Response:** 400 Bad Request

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Request message has unresolved parameters.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "Request message has unresolved parameters.",
      "type": "Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException",
      "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataRoutingConvention.SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup`2 actionMap)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a wrong Navigation property issue in request. There’s no `activitypointer_activity_parties_required` for sure.

Try this: (I haven’t tested it, can test in CRM REST Builder)

```
DELETE https://xxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/appointments(EE4C7268-81B7-E811-8143-3863BB368D98)/activitypointer_activity_parties(79ea68eb-4304-e911-8147-3863bb2eb450)
```

[activitypointer_activity_parties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/entities/activitypointer#BKMK_activitypointer_activity_parties)

**Update:**

Looks like we cannot achieve what you want. I played around a bit, nothing worked out but found these. We cannot do anything with ActivityParty records after creation, you have to manipulate them in form script or pre-create plugin itself before stored in DB.

> Entity Set Path [organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/activityparties
>
> Base Type crmbaseentity
>
> Display Name Activity Party
>
> Primary Key activitypartyid
>
> Primary Key Attribute partyidname
>
> **Operations Supported GET (RetrieveMultiple Only)**

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/activityparty?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

[Additional Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328224(v%3Dcrm.8))

Comment: Not Working Shows Error: **Operation not supported on appointment**